# Working with binary file - input order is wrong

Tags: c, binaryfiles

The following code takes user input and adds the data in a binary file which is names as a match.bin. The first input is taken successfully, but on the second time when it is asked, I cannot enter the id first. it directly asks about the name, surnames, job, and view. from what I see, the code should work perfectly fine, but I could not understand that why it is not working? Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
    
typedef struct{
    unsigned int id; // person id
    char name[20]; // person name
    char surname[20]; // person surname
    char job[20]; // job of person
    int view; // match view number of person
}personData;


int main(void){

    FILE *bfptr;

    if((bfptr = fopen("match.bin", "wb"))== NULL){
        puts("Could not open the file.");
    }
    else{
        personData blankrecord = {0, "", "", "",0};

        for(unsigned int i = 1; i<= 100; ++i)
            fwrite(&blankrecord, sizeof(personData), 1 , bfptr);
            
        fclose(bfptr);
    }
    
    if((bfptr = fopen("match.bin", "rb+"))==NULL){
        puts("Could not open the file in rb+ mode.");
    }
    else{
        personData person;

        printf("%s","Enter the Id number (1 to 100, put 0 to end input). ");
        scanf("%d", &person.id);


        while(person.id != 0){
            printf("%s", "Enther the Name, surname job and view:");
            scanf("%5s %5s %5s %1d",person.name,person.surname,person.job,&person.view);
    
            fseek(bfptr, (person.id - 1 )*sizeof(personData), SEEK_SET);
    
            fwrite(&person, sizeof(personData), 1 , bfptr);
    
            printf("%s", "Enter another Id: ");
            scanf("%d", &person.id);
        }

        fclose(bfptr);
    }

    personData persontemp[100];

    bfptr = fopen("match.bin", "rb");

    for(int i = 0; i <100; i++){
        fread(&persontemp[i], sizeof(persontemp[i]), 1 , bfptr);
        printf("%i %s %s %s %i\n",persontemp[i].id,persontemp[i].name,persontemp[i].surname,persontemp[i].job,persontemp[i].view);
    }
    fclose(bfptr);

}
```

Comment: You put `fclose(bfptr);` inside the loop, why?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. which one? I could not find the one which you are mentioning.

Comment: `puts("Could not open the file.");` - After this you should exit - as going further is not possible

Comment: The code formatting is horrible, but none of the `fclose`s is in a loop. What's your input? Your `%5s` conversions will read at most 5 characters. If any of your names are longer, the rest of the name will be considered the next input. That means you don't see a number where you expect it. Check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: @MOehm - I would go so far as to say it makes it unreadable

Comment: @MOehm, I understood what was the problem, Thank you, and I will work on the format of my coding style!

Comment: Good to hear you found the issue.

Comment: @MOehm indeed, it's a formatting problem...